# What's the purpose of the Direct3D import libraries?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, com, directx

From my understand those libraries are typically linked with explicit run-time linking (LoadLibrary), yet there are still those import libraries which contains descriptors to a small subset of the library. What's the reason for this?

Thanks in advance and greetings!

Comment: I think, it is used to know the addresses of the functions in those dll's, like they are function entry point address mapping

Comment: But this isn't required for the explicit run-time linking.

Comment: @Skeptiker if you use only and purely explicit run-time linking (LoadLibrary, and then GetProcAddress AND call through function pointers for every function call) than you are right, no reason to link to libs (for calling functions)

Comment: Ease-of-use and security. Many of the utility libs such as D3DX and D3DCompiler now use versioning, which the libs will automatically account for, but `LoadLibrary` won't. unless you have a very good reason (such as multiple render back-ends), you *should* be using the libs (which contain the global interfaces for the COM objects), not `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @Necrolis that would explain a lot! Great point!

Answer (score 3):

The "import libraries" are exactly that: small stubs that contain the address of the real function to call inside the DLL.
Here is a great post explaining [why you need import libraries](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/13/9906359.aspx)
You may also want to read about how linking works in the Windows world [on the same (great) blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/12/9905953.aspx)

And if you are curious about the other end of the story (execution time), there are some great articles on how Windows loads the needed DLLs, for [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301727.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985992.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx), which is useful to understand why/how your program does not call LoadLibrary (directly)

> When you use code or data from another DLL, you're importing it. When any PE file loads, one of the jobs of the Windows loader is to locate all the imported functions and data and make those addresses available to the file being loaded.

It is the loader that, based on what the linker wrote in the IAT, loads the DLL(s) fro you
(There was an even more interesting article on the NT insider, but I cannot find it online).

They are there to "make the linker happy", providing information that is (was) not present in the DLLs alone.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, however this doesn't seem to address my question. Perhaps the last sentence is meant to do that, however it's very vague.

The import library only contains a very small subset of the library functionality.

Comment: Ummm... let me clarify a bit. You generally do not use LoadLibrary directly, you link to stubs, which are little libs that contain only the info to locate a function. The linker needs them to resolve function names, and put the info in the EXE that will be later used by the OS. Then the OS (the Loader, specifically) loads the DLL for you.

Comment: Also, libs are general container for symbols and code: they are just a bunch of .obj files (compiled .cpp files) bound together. So you have functions AND global constants.
IIRC, DirectX uses libs for this purpose too: define constants, that are later used by your app. CAPS and device-ids are an example (again, IIRC)

Comment: No, an import library is not required and explicit run-time linking with LoadLibrary is common practice.

Comment: @Skeptiker an import library is not required for explicit run-time linking with LoadLibrary -> true. "is common practice"... not really. Why should it be so?

Comment: If you are using (and you can! It is only extremely inconvenient) only explicit run-time linking, than your program have to compile and run without any .lib file (after all, this is how it works with p/invoke on .NET)

Comment: I know that implicit linking is more common, I was just refuting your false statement that "You generally do not use LoadLibrary directly".

The import library does not contain (data) constants.

My question has still not been addressed. The import libraries only contain a small function subset of the library and I don't understand why.

Comment: Oh, I meant "You generally do not use LoadLibrary directly (when programming and calling functions a DLL, DirectX or not)". I thought that was clear, I was referring to linking in general, not to explicit (dynamic) linking. To help us understand and answer, you should point out which functions are missing (I find it quite strange.. do you get linking errors? if so, which errors? Are they in the headers, documented, undocumented and you found them using some tool...)

Comment: I don't have any technical issues. I have just noticed the small size of these import libraries and looked inside them. Only about 1% of the functions are represented there.

Comment: @Skeptiker now it is cleared, and I'm curious too... which libs have you examined? An example of a function that is missing?

Comment: It's the same with every Direct3D library. As I already said, almost all functions are missing.